# Exchange 2013 send connector issue

Tags: exchange-2013

Hi I am new for exchange server . In my organisation we having exchange server 2013 & I had purchase 2 domain from hosting provider. I want to configure both the domain with my exchange server. My problem is currently on one send connector is working which used for send the emails. I want to configure two send connectors to my two different domains.

Domain 1 emails should be send through domain 1 send connector and domain 2 emails should be send through domain 2 send connectors.

Also, note i have not created child domain, i have only added the authoritative domain and email address policy is created for the same.

To use both the domain for different send connectors, what procedure we should follow.

Request you to suggest the same.

Regards

Shadab Ansari

Answer (score 0):

The question that has to be asked is why?

Exchange doesn't route based on the originating domain, only on the recipient domain. Therefore out of the box, what you want to do isn't possible, and isn't necessary.

To work correctly, you just need a static IP address. Decide on a host name that will apply to your Exchange server and configure an A record for that host name in either of the two domains. Ask the ISP to set a PTR to match that host name, and configure the host name in the FQDN field of your send connector.

As long as all three things match, then you will be able to send email for any domain hosted by the Exchange server.

If you insist, then you will have to use a third party transport agent known as a sender based routing agent.